# What is MISRA 8-0-1 rule on init-declarator-list and member-declarator-list about?

Tags: c++, coding-standards

I am reading company's coding guidelines, and I encountered the [MISRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_Industry_Software_Reliability_Association) 8-0-1 rule, which states:

> An init-declarator-list or a member-declarator-list shall consist of a
>   single init-declarator or member-declarator respectively.

No example.

So, what is this rule about? Can anyone provide some example of this (bad and good)?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the MISRA-C++ 2008 manual, if so there are examples (page 115), such as: int32_t *i3, &j3 = i2;
and other ugliness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of init-declarator-lists is:

```
init-declarator-list:
       init-declarator
       init-declarator-list , init-declarator
init-declarator:
       declarator initializer
```

So it seems they are saying a init-declarator-list should contain only 1 init-declarator at a time.

so instead of

```
int a,b;
```

they want

```
int a;
int b;
```

(although they could be talking about initialisation fo the variable too, ie `int a = 0;` and not `int a = 0, b = 0;` even they do not talk about initalizers only init-declarators)

my opinion: "meh". This is why coding standards are poop.

Comment: I assume part of the motivation is to avoid weirdness like `int* a, b;`

Comment: Anything that could be slightly ambiguous for a casual reader is removed in MISRA-C. For example `int* a, b;`. This is for critical systems, and in those areas they still use old but trusted tools. Restricting the language a lot simplifies the work of analyzers (I guess)

Comment: doh so simple. Couldn't they just put such example in the document?!?

Comment: @Ixrec sure, but I'd expect a coder to know better, or a code reviewer to slap anyone who didn't. But fair enough if Misra is for critical systems.

Comment: Right, say you're in a code review, you see something like this: 
int & k1 = *i1, l1;
you'll want an explanation right? That's all MISRA is about, tells the developer to fix it or provide an explanation before wasting time in code review.

Comment: @Veriloud time spent in code review is never wasted. If everyone followed the standards perfectly then they wouldn't be needed, but they always are, even if someone has followed the standards perfectly!